# What species were the two women Kirk slept with in Star Trek Into Darkness?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-into-darkness

In *Star Trek Into Darkness*, Kirk slept with two non-human women, who had tails.

[image: Kirk's tailed girls in Star Trek Into Darkness]

One more distinctive feature was backbone kind of structure running through their neck:

[image: Kirk's girls in Star Trek Into Darkness]

Can you identify their species? Have we encountered them before in the entire history of Star Trek?

Comment: -1 no research: a simple Google image search would have sufficed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [an interview Damon Lindelof gave to StarTrek.com](http://www.startrek.com/article/exclusive-interview-damon-lindelof), they are **Caitians**:

> Can you confirm that the creatures we see with Kirk during his off-hours on Earth are Caitians?
>
> **Lindelof:** You mean the women with the tails? *[...]* Yes, we can confirm this.

We've seen Caitians a handful of times, but this is the only time we've seen Caitian females in live action:

- [Lieutenant M'Ress](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/M%27Ress) was a female Operations officer in *Star Trek: The Animated Series*

  [image]
- Two unnamed male Caitians were shown to be members of the Federation Council in *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home*

  [image]

  [image]

Comment: What about those furs?

Comment: @SS- Maybe they're members of a subspecies, or they're not pure Caitians. Or maybe it's the Klingons all over again, and special effects continues marching on

Comment: Or maybe someone watched too much Avatar :)

Comment: @DVK I can just imagine that planning meeting; "*Avatar* made a ton of money; must have been the cat-people! We need cat-people in our movie too!" "Sure JJ, whatever you say"

Answer (score 7):

> Kirk is seen in bed with two **Caitains** (according to STID screenwriter **Roberto Orci**) – a feline species first introduced in Star Trek: The Animated Series with the character M’Ress

source: http://trekmovie.com/2013/09/11/star-trek-into-darkness-easter-eggs-blu-ray-edition/

This is easy to discover if you do a Google Image search by your image while adding "star trek darkness" text

Answer (score 2):

They are Caitians, just their version of them for his universe is quite different than previous iterations.  It's a completely alternate universe, so something obviously happened to make them develop differently in this one.

Caitians have existed since at least 1973 in Star Trek, so no, they're not copied from Avatar.

Comment: It's not completely alternate universe like different canon. A photo from TOS and lots of other data exist in the new timeline. I don't think a timeline diversion would shave their bodies.